# Original error: Cannot read property 'forceStop' of undefined Appium, Ubuntu

Tags: automated-tests, ubuntu-16.04, python-appium

I have problem with appium mobile tests. I am new at QA tester. Earlier i write web automotion tests and i dont have these problems. I setup tests i write one. Still have the same problem

```
import os
import unittest
from appium import webdriver

class AndroidTests(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        desired_capabilities = {}
        desired_capabilities['platformName'] = 'Android'
        desired_capabilities['version'] = '5.0.1'
        desired_capabilities['deviceName'] = 'Android Device'
        desired_capabilities['app'] = os.path.abspath(
            os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '/home/tom/seller.apk'))

        self.driver = webdriver.Remote('http://localhost:4723/wd/hub', desired_capabilities)

    def tearDown(self):
        # end the session
        self.driver.quit()

    def test_Log_good(self):
      self.driver.find_element_by_id(ID.et_login).clear()
      self.driver.find_element_by_id(ID.et_login).send_keys('admin')
      self.driver.find_element_by_id(ID.et_password).clear()
      self.driver.find_element_by_id(ID.et_password).send_keys('login')
      self.driver.find_element_by_id(ID.btn_login).click()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    suite = unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromTestCase(AndroidTests)
    unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=2).run(suite)
```

The error display:
WebDriverException: Message: An unknown server-side error occurred  while processing the command. Original error: Cannot read property 'forceStop' of undefined

I think the problem is with the setup. I work on ubuntu 16.

Answer (score 2):

I was getting the same error, but I found a post that recommended re-installing appium with the `--no-shrinkwrap` option. That worked for me.

try re-installing appium:

```
npm install -g appium --no-shrinkwrap
```

source:
https://discuss.appium.io/t/appium-1-6-mjsonwp-cannot-read-property-forcestop-of-undefined/12857/2